# Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (Dimension(100), 1). Consider casting elements to a supported type

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer
from tensorflow.keras import backend as k
class attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(attention,self).__init__()
    def build(self,input_shape):
        self.W=self.add_weight(name="att_weight",shape=(input_shape[-1],1),initializer="normal")
        self.b=self.add_weight(name="att_bias",shape=(input_shape[1],1),initializer="zeros")
        super(attention,self).build(input_shape)
    def call(self,x):
        e=k.squeeze(k.tanh(k.dot(x,self.W)+self.b),axis=-1)
        a=k.softmax(e)
        a=k.expand_dims(a,axis=-1)
        output=x*a
        return k.sum(output,axis=1)
    def compute_output_shape(self,input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0],input_shape[-1])

    def get_config(self):
        return super(attention,self).get_config()
```

Below code showing input shape error.It is showing error TypeError: Failed to convert object of type  to Tensor. Contents: (Dimension(100), 1). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

```
inputs1=tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(32,))
x1=tf.keras.layers.Embedding(1879,32,
         input_length=32,embeddings_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(.001))(inputs1)
x1=tf.keras.layers.LSTM(100,return_sequences=True,dropout=0.3,recurrent_dropout=0.2)(x1)
outputs1=attention()(x1)
outputs1=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid',trainable=True)(outputs1)
Model=tf.keras.Sequential()
model1=tf.keras.Model(inputs1,outputs1)
```

Comment: here the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62948332/how-to-add-attention-layer-to-a-bi-lstm/62949137#62949137